# PHP Carbon Laravel - No 022017

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I need to get the last 13 months starting from the current month but when I try the code below. It gets every month but 022017. Any suggestions on why?

```
for ($i = 13; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $dates->addDate(Carbon::now()->subMonth($i)->format('mY'));
}
```

results:

```
0 => "082016"
1 => "092016"
2 => "102016"
3 => "112016"
4 => "122016"
5 => "012017"
6 => "032017"
7 => "042017"
8 => "052017"
9 => "062017"
10 => "072017"
11 => "082017"
```

Comment: This year February had only 28 days. Maybe that's the reason.

Comment: This gets asked on a  monthly basis, always at the end of the month, for obvious reasons.... work using the first day of the month, not days that don't exist in some months

Comment: Did you try to use the 1st of the current month as the starting point instead of `Carbon::now()`

Comment: Thanks after I added ->startOfMonth() it works now! Didn't think of that :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use `Carbon::now()` and you send this question on the 29th. It will skip february because there are only 28 days for that month.

Something like this should work:

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$month = $now->day = 1;
for ($i = 13; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $month->subMonth();
    $dates->addDate($month->format('mY'));
}
```